# Vector space property proof verification

Tags: linear-algebra

My problem is from Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, Spence:

In any vector space $V$, show that $(a+b)(x+y)=ax+ay+bx+by$ for any $x,y$ in $V$, and any $a,b$ in F.

My approach is:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
(a+b)(x+y) &=& (a+b)x+(a+b)y \\ \\
&=& ax+bx+ay+by \\ \\
&=& ax+ay+bx+by
\end{eqnarray*}$$

However, this seems too obvious to me and I'm wondering if I'm missing anything?

Comment: I think the point is to be aware which axioms of vector spaces you've used, e.g. commutativity of the + operation in the last step, etc.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Towards achieving the goal intended by the exercise you might want to indicate exactly which axiom you used in your deductions. Like, \begin{eqnarray*}
(a+b)(x+y) &=& (a+b)x+(a+b)y \;\; \text {VS 7} \\ \\
&=& ax+bx+ay+by \;\; \text {VS 8} \\ \\
&=& ax+ay+bx+by \;\; \text {VS 1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being pointed out what I need to do, here's my answer:

Let $(a+b)=c\in F$ (By closure of addition in fields)

$\Rightarrow c(x+y)=cx+cy$ (By scalar distribution)

i.e. $(a+b)\cdot(x+y)=(a+b)x+(a+b)y$

$\Rightarrow (a+b)\cdot(x+y)=ax+bx+ay+by$ (By vector distribution)

$\Rightarrow (a+b)\cdot(x+y)=ax+ay+bx+by$ (By commutativity of addition in vector space $V$)